# Different buttons for open and close nav menu

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a different button to open the menu options and a different button placed somewhere else to close the menu options. With the JS code below I can use  only one button to toggle and open the menu with options.

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.hamburger__container').click(function() {
            $('.nav').toggleClass('open');
            $('.controls').toggleClass('open2');
            $(this).children().first().toggleClass('open');
            $('html, body').toggleClass('noscroll');
        });

        // Bacon Ipsum
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=2&start-with-lorem=1&format=html',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#content').html(data);
            }
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

and HTML code:

```
        <button class="quality">
              <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve">
<metadata> Svg Vector Icons : http://www.onlinewebfonts.com/icon </metadata>
<g><path d="M893.8,294.1H655.5c49-32.1,95.4-73.9,100.8-119.5c2.7-22.2-2.5-54.8-42.7-83.9c-22.3-16.1-44.9-24.3-67.2-24.3c-70.9,0-111,79.5-132.7,150.6c-25.8-90.6-75.9-207-161.8-207c-25.1,0-50,9.9-74.3,29.5c-47.8,38.7-52.6,78.9-48.1,105.8c10,60.2,76.3,112,140.1,148.7H106.2c-19.3,0-34.9,15.3-34.9,34.1v186.3c0,18.8,15.6,34.1,34.9,34.1h9.1v407.4c0,18.8,15.6,34.1,34.9,34.1h699.6c19.3,0,35-15.3,35-34.1V548.5h9.1c19.4,0,35-15.3,35-34.1V328.1C928.8,309.3,913.1,294.1,893.8,294.1L893.8,294.1z M858.8,477.2H566.6v-115h292.2V477.2L858.8,477.2z M646.4,134.6c6.9,0,15.7,3.7,25.6,10.9c16,11.6,15.1,18.7,14.9,21.1c-3,24.8-54,63.9-113.4,96.2C591,194.1,619.5,134.6,646.4,134.6L646.4,134.6z M298.5,134.4c-1-5.6-3.4-20.5,23.7-42.4c7.8-6.3,19.3-13.8,29.6-13.8c38.5,0,78,92.3,101.1,182.1C380.3,224.9,305.2,174.6,298.5,134.4L298.5,134.4z M437.1,362.2v115h-296v-115H437.1L437.1,362.2z M185.2,518.1h251.9v403.7H185.2V518.1L185.2,518.1z M566.7,921.8V518.1h248.1v403.7H566.7L566.7,921.8z"/></g>
</svg>

           <div class="point-x hamburger" style="transform: translate(150px);">
                <i></i>
                <i></i>
                <i></i>
            </div>
          
        </button>
```

There is also the CSS code and other part of HTML code but I though this part would be enough to show my point.
In the HTML code there is only one button that opens and closes the navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always "simulate" a click in a button from another button

just:

```
$('.otherButton').click(function () {
$('.hamburger__container').trigger("click"); // behaves like if the user had pressed the original button
});
```

or you could encapsulate your event in a function and use it in both buttons

```
let myEventHandler = function() {
    $('.nav').toggleClass('open');
    $('.controls').toggleClass('open2');
    $(this).children().first().toggleClass('open');
    $('html, body').toggleClass('noscroll');
}

$('.hamburger__container').click(myEventHandler );
// somwhere else in your code
$('.otherButton').click(myEventHandler );
```

or if both buttons exist in your code at the same time you can just target them both when initializing the event

```
$('.hamburger__container, .otherButton').click(function() {
    $('.nav').toggleClass('open');
    $('.controls').toggleClass('open2');
    $(this).children().first().toggleClass('open');
    $('html, body').toggleClass('noscroll');
});
```